# What's the best way to share a crucial missing detail in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently ran into a coding problem that took me over an hour of googling and reading through docs to figure out. When I search for this particular error, I keep coming to the same SO thread with almost 10K views. One of the answers was *almost* exactly what I was looking for, but not quite right. After a lot more research, I found an obscure question that provided the line that particular answer was missing, and when I add it in, the first answer works perfectly.

I don't particularly enjoy spending over an hour looking for a solution to a problem, and so I would love to help out people who look for the same problem in the future. What's the best/most effective way to do this? I can think of a couple ways:

- Add a comment on the answer that was missing details. I have already done this, but it seems like not enough. I would like to do more if I can. Especially since comments "are second-class citizens".
- Edit the missing line into their sample code. This is probably the best solution, but it seems weird/strange to edit the *code* of a post. I also am not sure that it will be accepted, since I am below 2K.
- Post another answer on the same thread, mentioning the first answer and explaining what it's missing. This doesn't seem like the right solution, since shouldn't answers be fully self-contained?
- Post another question, explaining why the first answer didn't fully answer it, and then self-answer. I like this solution, but it won't necessarily get as much visibility as something affecting the first answer.

So what is the preferred and most helpful way to do this?

Comment: I'd probably opt for pt 3.

Comment: I'd be inclined to wait more than forty minutes before worrying so much about it! The answer is five years old, at least give it a day or two to allow for time differences and working patterns.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean to wait for them to edit it in? I assume they won't since it's an unregistered user with only one answer. who last visited the site in 2012.

Comment: Fair point, they haven't responded to the other comment either!

Comment: I would say it depends on the existing answers and what that one line of code would change. Will it simply fix an omission? Then an edit is usually best. Will it update the answer for a new version of the library or tool? Then a comment or new answer might be better (although an edit in the form of "for versions newer than *n* also add: ..." might also be fine).

Comment: You could attribute, link to and then quote the relevant bits of the original answer (just in case it magically disappears along the line) and then add your additions to it, explaining in a little more detail just why the addition is crucial. That way it is self-contained and can be read without interruption.